# Jquery apprise v2 2 buttons

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

Hey all i am trying to add a second button to this Apprise V2 JS code. However, i can not seem to get the correct click event for whichever one was clicked on.

Adding the buttons part of the code:

```
// Add buttons
$.each(settings.buttons, function(i, button) {

    if(button) {            
        button.id = "Accept";
        button.text = "Accept";

        var $_button = $('<button id="apprise-btn-' + button.id + '">').append(button.text);

        button.className = "green";
        $_button.addClass(button.className);
        $_buttons.append($_button);         
        $_button.on("click", function() {
            var response = {
                clicked: button,
            };

            button.action(response);
        });

        // Deny button
        button.id = "Deny";
        button.text = "Deny";

        var $_button = $('<button id="apprise-btn-' + button.id + '">').append(button.text);

        button.className = "red";
        $_button.addClass(button.className);
        $_buttons.append($_button);
        $_button.on("click", function() {
            var response = {
                clicked: button,
            };

            button.action(response);
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the part of the code that fires the box:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#custom-tryit').on("click", function() {     
        var $response = $('custom-response');       
        var options = { 
            buttons: { 
                confirm: {
                    text: 'Accept', 
                    className: 'blue', 
                    action: function(e) { 
                    console.log(this.id);

                        if (this.id == 'Deny') {
                            //Goto home page
                            console.log('home page');
                        } else {
                            //carry on
                            console.log('carry on');
                        }

                        Apprise('close'); 
                    }
                },
            },
            input: false
        };  

        Apprise('This is just a test here', options);
    });
});
```

The original code didn't seem to have an option for more than 1 button... The output seems to be outputting both values instead of just what was clicked on (console.log(this.id);):

```
Deny
home page
```

Any help would be great!

The [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgdYh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the response from:

```
$_button.on("click", function() {
            var response = {
                clicked: button,
            };
```

to

```
$_button.on("click", function() {
            var response = {
                clicked: "Accept",
            };
```

and did the same for the deny button.

then in the click event for

```
$('#custom-tryit')
```

I used

```
if ( e.clicked == 'Deny') {
```

instead of this.id, it seems to work fine. Check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/b2YZH/